# How to get a unit count of records from total count of record

Tags: c#

I have a gridview on aspx page. I'm filtering by units, example: unit 1, unit 2 and so on. By default when the page opens I get the total count of records in my database:

```
protected void sdsTACStudents_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSearchByName.Text == "")
            {
                int rowCount = e.AffectedRows;
                txtRecordCount.Text = rowCount.ToString();
            }
        }
But if ddlSearchBy.Text == "Last Name, "First Name" or "ssn", I need to display the current units count:
protected void sdsTACStudents_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSearchByName.Text == "")
            {
                int rowCount = e.AffectedRows;
                txtRecordCount.Text = rowCount.ToString();
            }
            else if ((ddlSearchBy.Text == "Last Name") || (ddlSearchBy.Text == "First Name") || (ddlSearchBy.Text == "SSN"))
            {
                display the current unit count which is less than the total count of all units.
            }
        }
```

Do I need to use a stored procedure to get the number of people in the unit?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is Yes. You need a stored procedure or parametrized query that can take any of those parameters (Last Name, First Name or SSN) and return the number of rows that match the criteria.

One example would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM_RECORDS FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%'+@FirstName+'%'; -- assuming you only want to do partial matching
```

It's up to you whether you create a stored proc or simply create a parametrized query, but this is the general idea.